# WebClient, when downloading, makes my app freeze (no-response). Why?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I have a **WPF** application programmed in **C#**. It works etc., but as soon as *client.DownloadFile()* is executed my app freezes (goes no-reponse) and anything that should happen while downloading (like progress bar or MB downloaded) is freezed.

It does download in fact *(File downloads, incorrupted)*, but it freezes like I said and I can't perform any mid-download actions such like updating bar, percentage etc. which **ARE cool**. From what I've seen, it shouldn't work like that.

Please do not mark as duplicate, I searched  google and stackoverflow and nothing helped me yet. I don't want to waste my whole day on searching, when I can ask and get answer 1 sec!

***Thanks.***

Comment: u need to use the async and await keywords client.DownloadFileAsync()

Comment: It freezes because the method is not async therefore its stuvk until it finishes.   Look for the async version

Comment: When it's async it shows weird errors, but I'll try